# Problems loading image from web in control template

Tags: image, web, controls

Problems loading image from web in control template

I try to read html content from database and display it in page:

I design a control template for this control, the generic.xaml likes following:

> ```
> <Style TargetType="q:ChoiceQuestion">
>         <Setter Property="Template">
>             <Setter.Value>
>                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="q:ChoiceQuestion">
>                     <RichTextBlock x:Name="QuestionTitleTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Center">
>                         <Paragraph x:Name="QuestionTitleParagraph">
>                             <Run Text="{Binding OrderNumber}"></Run>
>                         </Paragraph>
>                     </RichTextBlock>
>                 </ControlTemplate>
>             </Setter.Value>
>         </Setter>
>     </Style>
> ```

I get these pictures from html content and add it to QuestionTitleParagraph, so I write the following code to display image in OnApplyTemplate：

> ```
> public override void OnApplyTemplate()
>         {
>             base.OnApplyTemplate();
>
>             // Get the image url from database, the following image is just for test
>             ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://localhost:8081/uploadfile/2012/07/19/temp1.png",
> ```
>
> UriKind.Absolute));
>                   Image img = new Image();
>                   img.Source = imageSource;
>                   img.Width = 100;
>                   img.Height = 100;
>
> ```
>             // Add the image to QuestionTitleParagraph
>             QuestionTitleParagraph = (Paragraph)base.GetTemplateChild("QuestionTitleParagraph");
>             InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer();
>             container.Child = img;
>             QuestionTitleParagraph.Inlines.Add(container);
>         }
> ```

My problem is that it only dispaly a blank image in my page, and the size is as same as I desiged (100*100). How can I dynamically display image in control template? I am sure that the image url is valid, I can display it in richtextblock not in control template. And I found that if I don't set the width and height for image, it also can't display in richtextblock.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to change the picture format?